# GWT CellTable/DataGrid - how to detect column selection?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-celltable

When a row is selected, I would like to know which column of that row was selected.

Currently, I would override onBrowserEvent2

```
protected void onBrowserEvent2(Event event)
{
  // Get the event target.
  EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
  if (!Element.is(eventTarget)){
    return;
  }

  final Element target = event.getEventTarget().cast();

  // Find the cell where the event occurred.
  TableCellElement tableCell = findNearestParentCell(target);
  if (tableCell == null) {
    return;
  }

  int col = tableCell.getCellIndex();

  .... blah ... blah ....
}
```

where,

```
//exact replica code from {@link AbstractCellTable} private method findNearestParentCell
private TableCellElement findNearestParentCell(Element elem) {
  while ((elem != null) && (elem != getElement())) {
    // TODO: We need is() implementations in all Element subclasses.
    // This would allow us to use TableCellElement.is() -- much cleaner.
    String tagName = elem.getTagName();
    if ("td".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName) || "th".equalsIgnoreCase(tagName)) {
      return elem.cast();
    }
    elem = elem.getParentElement();
  }
  return null;
}
```

Is this the only way? Is there a selection model with a change event that would tell me which column of the row was clicked.

Is there a way to implement a click handler on a column or the cell of the column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG ... this was a really simple solution.

Use an extension of ClickableTextCell for the column.

```
public class SelectableTextCell
extends ClickableTextCell
{
  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(
    Context context,
    Element parent,
    String value,
    NativeEvent event,
    ValueUpdater<String> valueUpdater)
  {
    GWT.log("event="+event.getType()); //$NON-NLS-1$
    doYourThing();
    if (IWishToPropagateTheClick)
      super.onBrowserEvent(context, parent, value, event, valueUpdater);
  }
}
```

Or for a more general case, extend AbstractCell, and specify the consumed events at the constructor.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that in the above example you can reference context.getColumn(), which will return the column index of your cell.