# How to add click handler to GWT ImageResource cell?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

Please help me out with this problem.
I have this code below,I actually want to insert an image into a GWT datagrid and add a click handler to the image. But it is not responding to clicks, pls what do you think might be the problem?
This is the Resource interface

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
     @Source("delete.png")
      ImageResource getDeleteImage();

     @Source("edit.png")
      ImageResource getEditImage();
}
```

Below is the ImageResource Cell that I coded, but it is not responding to clicks.

```
DataGrid<AccountDTO> dataGrid = new DataGrid<AccountDTO>();

Column<AccountDTO, ImageResource>delete = new Column<AccountDTO, ImageResource>(new ImageResourceCell()) {

         @Override
            public ImageResource getValue(AccountDTO object) {
              return resources.getDeleteImage();
            }
          };

       delete.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<AccountDTO, ImageResource>() {

            @Override
            public void update(int arg0, AccountDTO object, ImageResource resource) {

                Window.alert(object.getId() + "" + object.getChargeAccount());
                dataProvider.getList().remove(object);
                dataProvider.refresh();
                dataGrid.redraw();

}
dataGrid.addColumn(delete, "");
dataGrid.setColumnWidth(delete, 3.0, Unit.EM)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you have [use a custom cell by extending AbstractCell](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCustomCells.html#cell-onBrowserEvent) for cell table you would extend ClickableTextCell (have a look a [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564834/gwt-celltable-datagrid-how-to-detect-column-selection?answertab=oldest#tab-top)). But as you are using image in your cell it gets tricky. [This tutorial worked for us](http://webcentersuite.blogspot.be/2011/03/custom-gwt-clickable-cell-with-images.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but there is a much simpler solution than suggested in the other answer.

```
datagrid.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<AccountDTO>() {

    @Override
    public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<AccountDTO> event) {
        if ("click".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
            if (event.getColumn() == datagrid.getColumnIndex(myImageColumn)) {
                AccountDTO account = event.getValue();
                // Do what you need with a click
            }
        }
    }

});
```